# Stuck finding inverse Fourier transform.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have the equation $u_t - u_{xx} = f(x,t),\; x\in\mathbb{R},\;t>0$, with the initial condition $u(x,0) = 0$.

I think I see where this is going but I want to make sure I'm not going in the wrong direction. I took a Fourier transform and got

$$\tilde{u}(k,t) = \exp(-k^2t)\left[\int_{0}^t\exp(k^2\tau)f(k,\tau)d\tau + d(k)\right]$$

I think that the next step be to show that

$$\tilde{u}(k,0) = \int_{0}^0\exp(k^2\tau)f(k,\tau)d\tau + d(k)= d(k) = 0 $$, which would mean that

$$u(x,t) = \mathbf{F}^{-1}\left[\exp(-k^2t)\right]*\mathbf{F}^{1}\left[ \int_{0}^t\exp(k^2\tau)f(k,\tau)d\tau\right]$$ the first inverse is easy. Is the second just integration by parts?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

$$\tilde{u}(x,t) = \exp(-k^2t)\int_0^{\infty}\exp(k^2\tau)f(k,\tau)d\tau = \int_0^{\infty}\exp(k^2(\tau-t))f(k,\tau)d\tau  $$

Which means that
$$ u(x,t) = \int_0^{\infty} \int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\exp[-(x-k)^2/4(t-\tau)]}{\sqrt{4\pi(t-\tau)}}h(k,\tau)dkd\tau $$